# Playing sound file without looping

Tags: javascript, audio, keydown

**Pure JavaScript**. Wanna play a (typewriter) a sound (.wav) upon pressing a key. At the same time, a light turns on and stays lit as long as the key is pressed down. *The problem is that the sound file keeps looping until I release the key*. Is there a way to get the sound file only play once without looping even if I keep the key pressed down?

*script.js*

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", lightOn, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", lightOff, false);
let click = new Audio("../sound/click.wav");

function lightOn(key) {
  switch (key.keyCode) {
    case 65:
      // click.loop = false; <- tried this but does not prevent looping
      click.play();
      document.getElementById("a").style.color = "goldenrod";
  }
}

function lightOff() {
  document.querySelector(".typing").style.color = "#ccc";
}
```

Comment: can you show how you call lightOn ?

Comment: By using `addEventListener` which is listening for a `keydown` event. Each physical key has a code ("a" is 65, "b" is 66 etc.) and when a `keydown` event takes place, the `function` executes, changing the font color.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that the held down key restarts the audio.

Comment: Problem is that you don't check how many times holding key call handler function.:)  if you had put console.log in lightOn then you would know, figure out that is called multiple times. That why i ask about how you call this function.

Comment: keyCode is olde way. now is preferred e.key = "A" :) [check](https://thisthat.dev/key-vs-key-code-vs-which)

Comment: Can I get in touch with you? My e-mail is zsmonostori80@gmail.com

Comment: check mailbox:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run snipped keep key and look on  the console.....

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  console.log(e.key)
});
```

and now with prevent repeat

```js
    window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
      if(e.repeat) 
        return
      console.log(e.key)
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. Still looping as long as the key is pressed down.

Comment: @kityatyi can you show. how you call lighOn

Comment: See my reply above.

Answer (score 1):

[Document is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement). It says that it must be good to call `click.pause()`. But it must not be result you expect. To control in detail requires [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). It's so harder than the former, but it must be exciting so try it!

Comment: Thank you, Akihito. The sound still loops.